# How I can pass the Cloudflare checkbox with Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cloudflare

I would like to connect to a website with Puppeteer, but I am blocked by the Cloudflare checkobx of this website. even if I check it manually, the page is refreshed and I return to the checkbox. but I can't get to the login form.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
 
  await page.setDefaultTimeout(120000);

  await page.goto('https://example.com/login');

  

  await page.waitForSelector('.login__input');
  await page.click('.login__input');
  await page.waitForSelector('#j_username');
  await page.type('#j_username', 'LOGIN');
  await page.type('#j_password', 'PASSWORD');
  await page.click('[type="submit"]');
})();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBtGT.png)

I want to validate the cloudflare checkbox, and go to the next step

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason the cloudflare checkbox exists is precisely to prevent people from doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's similar to recaptcha, there are captcha bypass services you can use like 2captcha

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes** adding a UserAgent can help to skip the cloudflare protection page.

Try adding a valid UserAgent

```js
await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
```

After

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
```